# Who are these deities on the cow?

Tags: identification-request, cows

In the below picture, there are many deities and some rishis embodied on the cow. There are some deities are unknown to me, that i circled:-
[image]

So, my question is:-

- Who are these deities on the cow?
- Is that tortoise deity Kurma avatar of Vishnu or anyone else?